# prevention of a property reassignment

Tags: c#, properties

Usually, when I code property of classes that could be edited by the user with a binding of some kind... To prevent executing of GUI logic, I don't allow to assign the same value to the property:

```cs
public PMSAccountingYear AccountingYear{
    get { return _accountingYear; }
    set{
        if(_accountingYear == value)
            return;
        _accountingYear = value;
        NotifyOtherProperties();

        LogChanges();
        EmallToTheBoss();

        Errr();
        BlowBombInTheGarden();
        Etc();
    }
}
```

The condition check doesn't look elegantly, and cannot be detected with any automatic code analysis.
Can you please suggest a better case?
With one of the attributes maybe?

Comment: I think what you have here is just fine. I've used this exact model plenty of times.

Comment: Thanks. Just had nobody to ask how did it look. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly fine; this is the common way to implement setters for things like [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) (aee also the example on that page).

As the value did not change, there is no need to actually update the backing field and especially not to notify others of a “changed” value.